# meteor mup deploy failed

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

After `mup init` and `mup setup` server success with Meteor up, i run `mup deploy` and it fail at **Verifying Deployment: FAILED** :

```
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    node-gyp rebuild

    make: Entering directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
      COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
    make: Leaving directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
    bcrypt@0.8.7 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
    bindings@1.2.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bindings
    nan@2.3.5 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/nan

    > buffertools@2.1.4 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bufferstream/node_modules/buffertools
    > node-gyp rebuild
```

I use Digital Ocean server on Ubuntu 14.04. I've install Node v4.4.7 and node-gyp.

If i run node-gyp rebuild, i've this error :

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:12:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: I am having this exact issue on digital ocean, did you ever solve it?

Comment: Yep, i've change the docker image from my mup.js : dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',

Comment: Thanks! Are you running meteor 1.4.1? I am still getting that error even with that docker image.

Comment: I run with 1.4. I do not have test with 1.4.1 ^^

Answer (score 0):

Meteor cannot find the module.
Usually running `meteor npm install <missing module>` solves the issue.
Try running `meteor npm install --save graceful-fs` before deploying.